# class inheritance and cookies in python

Tags: python, inheritance, cookies

I have a class called BlogHandler that has some basic functionality in it. I pass this class into another class called MainPage. I am trying to use a function from BlogHandler in my MainPage class, but it is saying it isn't defined.

```
class BlogHandler:
    def read_secure_cookie(self, name):
        cookie_val = self.request.cookies.get(name)
        return cookie_val and check_secure_val(cookie_val)


class MainPage(BlogHandler):
    def post(self):
        email = self.request.get('email')
        product = self.request.get('product')
        username = read_secure_cookie('content')
```

The 'content' of the cookie is 14|b670fedff24f182e52a1ceacf7790e02. How do I return just the 'cookie_val' and just the first part of the 'cookie_val' (the 14).

Thanks

Comment: It seems there are two questions here, if I'm not mistaken. For the second (how to return the first part of `cookie_value`) you can simply [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on the `|` character: `first_part = cookie_value.split('|')[0]`.

Comment: Chris- thanks. I also need to know how to just get cookie_val and not the second part of the return statement

Comment: I think @mach has addressed this in his edited answer. Is this what you meant? In the future you should only ask one question per post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first error, you need to use:

```
self.read_secure_cookie('content')
```

Any superclass methods must also be called with `self`. (There are other ways, but this is best practice.)

As for correcting your other problem (I'm assuming you want to return multiple values), just use a comma instead of `and`:

```
return cookie_val, check_secure_val(cookie_val)
```

For your third problem, split as Chris said:

```
cookie_value.split('|')[0]
```

Putting it all together:

```
class BlogHandler:
    def read_secure_cookie(self, name):
        cookie_val = self.request.cookies.get(name)
        return cookie_val, check_secure_val(cookie_val)

class MainPage(BlogHandler):
    def post(self):
        email = self.request.get('email')
        product = self.request.get('product')
        cookie_val, cookie_secure_val = self.read_secure_cookie('content')
        username = cookie_val.split("|")[0]
```

If I didn't understand you correctly, please say so!

Comment: mach- I need to leave read_secure_val alone because I use it elsewhere. CAn I use cookie_val = self.request.cookies.get('content') then username = cookie_val.split('|')[0]? I just tried this and I got an error saying "NoneType has no method split"

Comment: That error means your `self.request.cookies.get('content')` call is returning `None`. I'm just guessing, but it might return `None` if you are trying this from an interpreter window and not through how a normal user would access it (via web browser). If that call does indeed return `14|b670fedff24f182e52a1ceacf7790e02`, then the split method will work. You will have `14` stored in `username`.

Comment: I am running it on localhost in Chrome. I checked to make sure the cookie exists, but I am still getting NoneType object has no method split

Answer (score 1):

`read_secure_cookie`
Is an instance method of the BlogHandler class, which means that it requires the object as an argument.

By extending and adding functionality to in the `MainPage` class, you have inherited the instance methods, and can access them in the same was as all instance methods in Python, you need to add the keyword `self` i.e.

`username = self.read_secure_cookie('content')`

To answer your second question, given a string with contents `myStr = '14|b670fedff24f182e52a1ceacf7790e02'` the easiest way to split it is to first find the character you wish to split at:
`ind = string.find('|')`
and then split it into two sections:

`first  = myStr[:ind]
end = myStr[ind:]`